# EmberJS get dynamic parameter in nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am developing a website using Ember JS.
I have created a nested route like this:

```
//router
this.resource('store/checkout', {path: '/store/checkout/:order_id'}, function(){
      this.resource('store/checkout-lines', {path: ''});
  });
```

This results in the route /store/checkout/:order_id calling both routes and corresponding tempaltes.
The template for store/checkout has an `{{outlet}}` for the template store/checkout-lines.
In the routes I have this code:

```
//store/chekout
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('order', params.order_id);
    }
});

//store/checkout-lines
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var order_id = params.order_id; //this does not work
        return this.store.find('order-item', {orderId: order_id});
    }
});
```

But my problem is that in the route for store/checkout-lines, I cannot get the orderId.
How can I achieve this? Or am I at the wrong track and should be doing this in another way?
My goal is that the route /store/checkout/:order_id should call the server to fetch both order and orderItems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What some people seem to miss is that even if you are visiting a nested route, the model for the parent route is loaded. In your nested route, you can easily fetch the model from the parent route using `modelFor(type)`and then get your information from there. In your case it would be like this.

```
//store/checkout-lines
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var order_id = this.modelFor('checkout').get('id');
        return this.store.find('order-item', { orderId: order_id });
    }
});
```

This might seem like an extra step but when you get around to it it really makes a lot of sense and works very well.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that I had access to the parent model in the route.